# get variables from regular expresion

Tags: php, regex

I have one of the following strings:

```
mystring
/mystring
mystring?test
/mystring?test
```

That is one string preceded by one optional `/` and followed by and optional `?test`

I need to get this variables:

```
$string = "mystring"
$test = false / true depending if ?test is present
```

I'm trying to use regular expressions but I'm having trouble with the right pattern. I'm trying:

```
\/?(\w+)(\??\w+)
```

For example, for "mystring", I'm getting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /mystring
    [1] => mystrin
    [2] => g
)
```

This is a sample code:

```
<?
echo "<pre>";

$input = "/mystring";

$pattern = "/\/?(\w+)(\??\w+)/";

$matches = null;

preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: You want `\/?\w+(?:\?\w+)?` or `^\/?\w+(?:\?\w+)?$`

Comment: Are you restricted to using a regex for some reason? Why not `parse_url`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not getting both variables with that pattern

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm not restricted to regex, I'm open to other approaches

Comment: Do you mean groups? Add them wherever you want, e.g. `\/?(\w+)(?:\?(\w+))?`, see https://regex101.com/r/BtCw27/1 and https://3v4l.org/Y2j6R

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's working nice!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what's the point of using double catch and then ignoring the outer one, why not simply move the \?? out of the catch, see my answer below for complete expression and answer

Comment: @NabeelKhan I already answered that below your answer. Your solution may match incomplete strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew apparently his code requirement doesn't get affected by empty ? being present at the end

Answer (score 1):

For a non-regex alternative if you're interested, you can use `parse_url`. It accepts partial URLs, and it can parse strings like those.

```
$components = parse_url($input);
```

`$string` is the path with leading slash removed, and `$test` is the equality of the query to the string 'test'.

```
$string = trim($components['path'], '/');
$test = isset($components['query']) && $components['query'] == 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're including the `?` in catch expression.

The regex you should use: `\/?(\w+)\??(\w+)?`

This will use less number of steps (46 compared to 56 of your regex) hence less load on the server too.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/98QNeh/2

Comment: Your regex [also matches](https://regex101.com/r/98QNeh/3) `/mystring?` which might not be what is required.

Comment: yes, you can go on the regex101 link in my answer and see the catch for each line